# How to calculate the power law exponent of a graph

Tags: graph, directed-graph, power-law

If I have a directed graph, with in-degree and out-degree for each vertex.

From plotting the in-degree and out-degree with the number of nodes have this in/out-degree, its clear from the curve that it follows the power law.

But how I can find the power low exponent?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Using the `igraph` package in RStudio, you can use the `fit_power_law` function:

`my_fit <- fit_power_law(degree(my_graph, mode = "all"), implementation = "plfit")`

And `my_fit$alpha` will, I think, be your power law exponent.

When posting questions next time, please indicate what software/language you're using to analyse your data, and provide some reproducible example of your data. =)

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can fit an OLS linear regression of the form

```
log(count_of_nodes) = a + b * log(degree)
```

The estimated coefficient `b` will be your exponent.